# Achieving sub-block non-malleability

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, format-preserving, shuffle

I have a noisy one-way communication channel where data is sent as a series of words of width *n* bits.
Assume *n* is a constant roughly in the range of 16...48.
I don't want bit errors in one word to affect the other words.

To achieve confidentiality in such a scenario, one would use a stream cipher,
as that guarantees that a bit error in the ciphertext only causes the corresponding plaintext bit
to be flipped.
In contrast, a block cipher (of width 128, typically) would operate on several words at once,
which would all be affected catastrophically by even a single bit flip.

A stream cipher, being malleable, enables an active attacker to target specific bits of the plaintext.
And with a known ciphertext / plaintext pair, the attacker can essentially forge any desired plaintext.

I'm interested in achieving per-word non-malleability.
It seems that applying a "mini block cipher" to each word would do that.

The [Swap-or-Not shuffle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1176) (by Hoang, Morris and Rogaway) looks promising.
It is defined as follows:

```
proc EKF(X)
for i ← 1 to r do
    X′ ← Kᵢ ⊕ X
    X̂ ← max(X,X′)
    if Fᵢ(X̂) = 1 then X ← X′
return X
```

I need to supply the subkeys *Kᵢ* and the round functions *Fᵢ*.
Here's what I've come up with: Since I'm intending to use a stream cipher anyway (reasoning below),
I have a keystream known to the sender and receiver but noone else.
For each round, I therefore consume *n* bits from the keystream for *Kᵢ* and one bit for *Fᵢ*, as follows:

```
Kᵢ ← {0,1}ⁿ  // from keystream

proc Fᵢ(X)
b ← {0,1}    // from keystream
return parity(X) ⊕ b
```

Where parity(*X*) is the boolean parity function: parity(*X*) = popcount(*X*) mod 2

After doing *r* shuffling rounds, I then apply the stream cipher in the usual way.
For each word, I therefore consume *r*(*n*+1)+*n* bits from the keystream.

The belt-and-suspenders approach of shuffle-then-cipher is reasonable in my opinion,
given that stream ciphers and modes (such as AES-CTR) are well studied,
as opposed to my instantiation of the Swap-or-Not shuffle.
Secondly, it allows me to be frugal with the keystream
by choosing a moderate number of rounds *r* for the shuffle,
because confidentiality is assured by the stream cipher.

I am aware that this scheme does not assure authenticity or integrity.
I'm simply interested in frustrating an attacker who intends to tamper with a ciphertext to obtain specific plaintext changes.

I have several questions:

1. Can shuffling the words before applying the stream cipher make any security property worse compared to just applying the stream cipher? I would assume not but would be gladly corrected.
2. Is my assumption correct that with sufficient rounds of a good shuffle procedure,
   an attacker is prevented from any targeted tampering of specific plaintext bits?
3. Are my methods for obtaining *Kᵢ* and the procedure *Fᵢ* sound?

   The first revision of the Swap-or-Not paper in section 6 introduced a realization with additional subkeys *Lᵢ*. In the second revision of the paper, that section (now numbered 7) points out that the function being linear makes the inner-product method breakable. How is that and does my method suffer the same problem?
4. Are there better methods?

   For example, would wrapping the Swap-or-Not in [Sometimes-Recurse](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/560) help
   reduce the required number of rounds for a given security level in this case?
   I have a hard time getting an intuitive understanding of how Sometimes-Recurse
   achieves thorough shuffling despite recursing on one half only.

   What I'm looking to achieve could be called format-preserving encryption on {0,1}*ⁿ* for *n* < 128.
   There is some activity at NIST, and I would certainly prefer something endorsed by a standards body,
   but it looks like FF1 and FF3 are patent-encumbered.